# How do I send an email directly from a gmail add on?

Tags: gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets, gmail-addons

I have developed a gmail add-on for personal use and it can currently draft a reply to a recipient using `message.createDraftReply(replyMessage);`. I then have to manually send email.

After the button click event, I would rather that the the email just be sent directly without further action needed on my end and the UI go back to the inbox (rather than the email view).

Is this possible? If so, can you please provide some direction/example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the sendEmail method?

See documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)